# UI view animation swipe up or down

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm having trouble getting this animation for swiping up or down to work. 
Here is my code so far. It only animates but object does not work when swiping on screen.

```
ViewController.m
//  notificationView

//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     NotificationView *notifications= [[NotificationView alloc]              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,200,200,200)];
      notifications.backgroundColor =[ UIColor blueColor];
       [self.view addSubview:notifications];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer            alloc]initWithTarget:self action:
    @selector(swipeUp:)];
    [notifications addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];

    swipeUp.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer            alloc]initWithTarget:self action:
    @selector(swipeDown:)];

    swipeDown.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
   [notifications addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        notifications.center=CGPointMake(150,150);}]; };

   -(void) swipeUp:(id) sender {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender;}

    -(void) swipeDown:(id) sender { }



@end
```

Comment: I think you are missing with delegate. set UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in header.

Answer (score 1):

Try this its work perfect.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    notifications = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,200,200,200)];
    notifications.backgroundColor =[ UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:notifications];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:
                                         @selector(swipeUp:)];
    [notifications addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];

    swipeUp.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:
                                         @selector(swipeDown:)];

    swipeDown.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [notifications addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        notifications.center=CGPointMake(150,150);
    }];
}

-(void) swipeUp:(id) sender {

   [self animationOfObject:150 yVlaue:150];
}

-(void) swipeDown:(id) sender {

  [self animationOfObject:150 yVlaue:300];
}

-(void)animationOfObject:(float)xValue yVlaue:(float)yValue
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        notifications.center=CGPointMake(xValue,yValue);
    }];
}
```

Comment: if you satisfied with my answer then don't forgate to right mark my answer.